# Question about C ! operator

Tags: c, logical-operators

My understanding of this is as follows. In C, the `!` operator returns 0 if it is given a nonzero value and returns a nonzero value if it is given 0.

Say you have this little snippet of C code:

```
int y = 0;
int z = !y;
```

What value will go into `z`? Does it simply take `!0` to be 1? Is it system dependent? Does the C standard dictate what is supposed to happen? I ran into these questions while doing some homework earlier tonight dealing with bitwise 2's-complement integer manipulation. I got a certain problem to work, but I'm sort of scratching my head as to *why* it works. Thanks a lot for any info!

Comment: Functions return a value.  Expressions are evaluated.  An expression in which ! is the last operator applied will evaluate to 1 or 0.

Comment: Who told you it returns "a nonzero value if it is given 0"? It returns 1 in this case. This is well-defined by the language.

Comment: I may have mixed myself up and mistakenly thought that since ! evaluates to 0 for any nonzero value as its operand, it somehow applied in reverse as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Truth values "generated by" C are always 0 or 1.

It is true (heh) that a non-zero expression is generally considered "true" in `if` and so on, but when the language itself needs to generate a truth value it uses 0 for false and 1 for true.

Since the `!` operator is a logical operator, it will always result in 0 or 1.

So in your case, `z` will be set to 1.

**Update**: See [this FAQ entry](http://c-faq.com/bool/bool2.html) for more discussion, that's what I had in mind with the "generated by" wording. Amazingly, it even has the same pun (I did not look this entry up before writing my answer). Not sure if this is an indication of me having a good sense of humor, or not.

Comment: `Truth values "generated by" C are always 0 or 1.`Wrong!! `if(1234)` is also true. True is any non-zero value.

Comment: I think `1234` in your example is not "generated by" C in the sense *unwind* had in mind.

Comment: @Acme: That's what he means by "generated by C".  i.e. the result of a logical or comparison operator (`!`, `<`, `&&`, etc.).

Comment: @Acme: Enough people have echoed what unwind said. But to put it in code: `!!1234` is `1`.

Comment: @Charles Bailey :: Try not to understand things too literally at times.

Answer (score 4):

The result of an unary-expression with the `!` operator is an `int` with value `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 3):

> The result of the logical negation
>   operator ! is 0 if the value of its
>   operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if
>   the value of its operand compares
>   equal to 0. The result has type int.
>   The expression !E is equivalent to
>   (0==E).

From The C Standard (n1124) section 6.5.3.3.